# How to set stylesheet for multiple buttons but not all

Tags: qt

I'm using a .qss file to set stylesheet for QPushButton I want to give some buttons a different style than other buttons... Is there any way to do this? Maybe something like

```
QPushButton#thisbutton{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a normal QButton you can do it like you write above:

```
QPushButton{ color: blue}
```

if you can, then extend with inheritance the button and do:

```
MyNewButtonClass{color: red}
```

or you can directly with the name of the object directly:

```
QPushButton#okButton { color: gray }
```

## update:

you can ofcourse set the style of buttons without duplicating the sheet...you just do:

```
QPushButton#okButton, QPushButton#acceptButton, QPushButton#cancelButton
{
    color: green 
}
```

Comment: Can't I give more than one name?

Comment: sure... let me update the answer

Comment: cant I write ```QPushbutton```  only once?

Answer (score 3):

In QT Designer, add a custom property and call it **class**:

[image]

Set the value for this:

[image]

In a CSS style sheet set formatting for this class:

[image]

That's it!