# QT: assign CSS class to some widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm developing a QT app, using C++, with a GUI. I set a stylesheet as an external file and when I write for example:

```
QLabel {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

It works perfectly.
Now, I would have inside my stylesheet some classes, as for the classic CSS:

```
.classname {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Searching in the web, I found the following solution:

1. Inside the QT Designer, add a dynamic property to the specific widget, named for example "cssClass", and type "String";
2. Inside the stylesheet, for example for the QLabel, write:

   QLabel[cssClass~="className"] {
   color: red;
   font-size: 15px;
   }
3. Inside the QT Designer associate the name "className" to the dynamic property "cssClass".

But this is not working.
Someone knows where is the error or another solution for my problem?
Thank you

UPDATE:
Yes, I can assign the properties to some widgets, calling the name:

```
QLabel#labelName {
    ...
}
```

But I have to list all the names inside the stylesheet. Is there a way to give only one class name? And the widgets call the class?
thanks

Comment: `QLabel#classname{color: red;font-size: 15px;}`

Comment: here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553926/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-multiple-buttons-but-not-all/69554415#69554415

Comment: If ClassName is a class that inherits from QWidget then you can directly do: `ClassName{color: red;font-size: 15px;}`

Answer (score -1):

as stated here: [How to set stylesheet for multiple buttons but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553926/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-multiple-buttons-but-not-all/69554415#69554415)
you can do that using the name of the instance

```
QPushButton#okButton { color: gray }
```