# Setting a QSS style on all QToolButtons in an application except the ones inside a QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar, qtoolbutton

The application I am working on uses QToolButtons as simple elements in a layout and as QActions added to QToolBars. I would like to apply a style on all the QToolButtons in my application except the ones within a QToolBar.
I saw that I can set a style on all QToolButtons with the entry:

```
QToolButton{ background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
```

And I can apply a style for all the QToolButtons inside a QToolBar using:

```
QToolBar > QToolButton { background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); }
```

But how can I perform the required styling without adding a style entry for the buttons in QToolBar, so that they would still have the default styling?

Comment: See this: [How to set stylesheet for multiple buttons but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553926/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-multiple-buttons-but-not-all), where this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72488168/17726418) implements this: [Customizing Using Dynamic Properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties), in Qt Designer.